# Simple shell with fork and exec

Tags: c, shell, fork, exec, implementation

I am trying to make a simple shell running any command from PATH, lets say ls or pwd du gedit etc. I am having trouble with exec.I require that if i enter space nothing happens and if i type exit it terminates.Any help is appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER 1024

int main() {
    char line[BUFFER];
    char* args[100];
    char* path = "";
    char program[20];


while(1){
    printf("$ ");
         if(!fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin))
          break;
          size_t length = strlen(line);
         if (line[length - 1] == '\n')
         line[length - 1] = '\0';
     if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0)  break;
         strcpy(program,path);           
         strcat(program,line);
    int pid= fork();              //fork child

        if(pid==0){               //Child
        execlp(program,line,(char *)NULL);    
    }else{                    //Parent
        wait(NULL);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have 2 `fgets()` call. Remove the first one `fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin);`.
2. `fgets()` will read in the newline if there's space in buffer. You need to remove it because when you input `exit`, you'll actually input `exit\n` and there's no command as `/bin/exit\n`.

The below code demonstrates removing newline character:

```
    if(!fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin))
        break;
    char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
    if (p) *p = 0;
```

3. Your usage is wrong. Check the manual of `execl`. You need to pass the arguments: `execl(program, line, (char *)NULL);`
   Notice the cast of last argument of `NULL`. In case, `NULL` is defined as `0` then the cast becomes necessary because `execl` is a variadic function.

---

A modified example using `execvp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER 1024

int main(void) {
    char line[BUFFER];

    while(1) {
        printf("$ ");
        if(!fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin)) break;
        char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
        if (p) *p = 0;
        if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0) break;
        char *args[] = {line, (char*)0};
        int pid= fork();              //fork child
        if(pid==0) {               //Child
            execvp(line, args);
            perror("exec");
            exit(1);
        } else {                    //Parent
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But i just saw i need to execute any program in $PATH directory. How can do this ? Also i want to to exit even if i type exit(any blank space after)

Comment: Then use the "path" variants of exec (`execlp`, `execvp`, or `execvpe`) which would search the PATH for commands. I have updated the answer which shows how to remove the newline using `strchr()`

Comment: I used execlp but du(disk usage) command or gedit doesnt work. If i am not mistaken that is on usr/bin and my path variable on the start of the code doesnt include it right ?

Comment: Yes, if you use the path variants then don't prepend `/bin/` (as you do in your code). You can find the actual path using shell command `which`. E.g., run `which gedit` and it'll give you the location.

Comment: Can you help me how to code it ? I cant get it right. Do i remove bin at the start ? Also i cant use which into a program can i ? I need to exec usr/bin or /bin/. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have modified your code to use `execvp`. If you want to pass arguments to your command, you need to parse your input and insert in `args` array.

Comment: It worked thank you. How can i parse arguments ? What library would you use ? I am asked to do ls -l /tmp for example or use cd with relative or absolutes paths with the help of chdir and getcwd.

Comment: If you input `ls -l` then think about how you can split that into arguments? For example you can use `strtok()` to split and store the individual parts (`ls` and `-l`) in an array and then call `execvp` as shown above. If you google about it, I am sure you can find a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Hi See my correction below and see my comment as well.

```
int main() {
char line[BUFFER];
char* args[100];
char* path = "/bin/";
char program[20];
char command[50];

while(1){
    printf("$ ");
    if(!fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin))
        break;
    memset(command,0,sizeof(command));
    if(strncmp(line, "exit", (strlen(line)-1))==0)  break;
    strncpy(command,line,(strlen(line)-1));
    strcpy(program, path);
    strcat(program,command);
    int pid= fork();              //fork child
    if(pid==0){               //Child
        execl(program,command,NULL);
        exit(0);// you must exit from the child because now you are inside while loop of child. Otherwise you have to type exit twice to exit from the application. Because your while loop also became the part of every child and from the child again it will call fork and create a child again
    }else{
        wait(NULL);
    }
 }
}
```

Also to support all command execution see the function `execl` how you need to pass the parameters in it. Accordingly you need to split your command and create the parameter list properly for `execl`.

Comment: How can i make it run any program in $PATH (also usr/bin lets say) and not only /bin/. I edited my original post.